# Filter column values in DataFrame based on if value contains a substring from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I would like to see which values in a specific column from dataframe #1 have substrings that are equal to the values in a corresponding column in dataframe #2.

```
data = {
  'id': ['TEST-123','WORD-456']
}

data2 = {
  'id':['123','456']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I tried using

```
df1 = df1[df1['id'].str.contains([i for i in df2.tolist()])]
```

but was met with a 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'' error.

My expected dataframe in this example would be df1 left unchanged because 'TEST-123' has the substring '123' from df2 and 'WORD-456' has the substring '456' from df2.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex to use with `str.contains`:

```
import re

mask = df1['id'].str.contains(df2['id'].map(re.escape).str.cat(sep='|'), regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1[mask]
         id
0  TEST-123
1  WORD-456

>>> mask
0    True
1    True
Name: id, dtype: bool

>>> df2['id'].map(re.escape).str.cat(sep='|')
'123|456'
```

Note, `str.contains` expects a string not a list of string.